# DataGrid content not showing

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm programming in WPF. I use these styles for DataGrid control:

```
    <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Block.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="*"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource CellStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="2  badr"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft"/>

        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="LightGray"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </Style>
```

I apply this style using a line of code, some thing like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg1" Style="{StaticResources DataGridStyle}"
```

and then populate it using a DataSet(programaticaly).

Now some data does not show. How can I fix this problem?
[image: Picture of DataGrid]

also I use this code:

```
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
```

but it is not working

Comment: How do you apply those styles, how do you fill the data ?

Comment: Please consider asking two separate questions.

Comment: show your complete code

Comment: if you don't post your code we cant guess what wrong, though its probably a binding issue. check output window while debugging or use snoop